# How to set the cursor position in nsIEditor/nsIPlaintextEditor via javascript in a Thunderbird extension?

Tags: javascript, plugins, xul, thunderbird-addon

I'm trying to create a simple Thunderbird extension which operates on `plain/text` messages when replying to a message. After applying modifications to current editor's content I need to place the cursor on a specific position, because now the cursor is always placed on the end of the reply.

Is this possible? I searched almost everywhere, but did not find a solution.
I've spent hours here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/NsIEditor
- http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/HowTos/Common_Thunderbird_Use_Cases/Compose_New_Message.html#Modify_Message_Body
- and others (I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links).

Few words about the plugin. The plugin does one simple job, it removes all "empty" lines from the quoted message when replying. A simplified version of my JavaScript file:

```
var myStateListener = {
    init: function (e) {
        gMsgCompose.RegisterStateListener(myStateListener);
    },
    NotifyComposeFieldsReady: function () {
        // alter message fields here
    },
    NotifyComposeBodyReady: function () {
        // alter message body here
        try {
            var editor = GetCurrentEditor();
            var editor_type = GetCurrentEditorType();
            editor.beginTransaction();
            editor.beginningOfDocument();
            // plain text editor
            if (editor_type == "textmail" || editor_type == "text") {
                var content = editor.outputToString('text/plain', 4);
                var contentArray = content.split(/\r?\n/);
                var contentArrayLength = contentArray.length;
                var newContentArray = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < contentArrayLength; i++) {
                    // match "non-empty" lines
                    if (!/^>{1,} *$/.test(contentArray[i])) {
                        // Add non-matching rows
                        newContentArray.push(contentArray[i]);
                    }
                }
                // join array of newContent lines
                newContent = newContentArray.join("\r\n");
                // select current content
                editor.selectAll();
                // replace selected editor content with cleaned-up content
                editor.insertText(newContent);
            } else {
                // HTML messages not handled yet
                void(null);
            }
            editor.endTransaction();
        } catch (ex) {
            Components.utils.reportError(ex);
            return false;
        }
    },
    ComposeProcessDone: function (aResult) {
        //
    },
    SaveInFolderDone: function (folderURI) {
        //
    }
};
//
window.addEventListener("compose-window-init", myStateListener.init, true);
```

I'm a newbie when it comes to Thunderbird Plugins, so any help will be appreciated. What should I read, where can I find a complete and valid documentation, examples etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Programmers doesn't accept questions about implementing code or locating documentation, examples or other resources.

Comment: I have flagged for migration to StackOverflow.

Comment: OK, sorry and thank You for migrating my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently creating an extension too, so i faced a similar problem. To be honest, the mdn doc is a real disappointment

```
var sr = editor.selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange(); // old cursor
var range = editor.document.createRange(); // prepare new cursor
// do stuff to the editor
range.setStart(sr.startContainer, editor.selection.focusNode.textContent.length);
range.setEnd(sr.startContainer, editor.selection.focusNode.textContent.length);
editor.selection.removeAllRanges();
editor.selection.addRange(range);
```

For more information, i recommend to read this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range and this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

With `range.setStart()` and `range.setEnd()` you can define where the cursor has to be. The example above will set the cursor right to the end of the manipulated text.
But i'm not sure if `removeAllranges()` can cause issues.